# How to tell ServiceHost to load assembly from any directory

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service library and a windows service as a host.
I would like to make ServiceHost to load WCF service library(to get service type from that assembly) from any directory and not only from current dir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is configuration -

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="MyAssembly2"  culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="307041694a995978"/>
            <codeBase version="1.0.1524.23149" href="FILE://C:/Myassemblies/MyAssembly2.dll"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Another way is code -
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(path);